# Django's JsonResponse is not JSON serializable - why?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, serialization

I'm trying to get up and running with an API that already works for some others (who, of course, I can't consult right now). I get an error for one specific endpoint:

```
TypeError: dict_values([
{'unregistered_users': 2, 'group_name': 'a', 'registered_users': 9, 'total_users': 11}, 
{'unregistered_users': 0, 'group_name': 'b', 'registered_users': 4, 'total_users': 4},
{'unregistered_users': 0, 'group_name': 'c', 'registered_users': 4, 'total_users': 4}, 
{'unregistered_users': 4, 'group_name': 'd', 'registered_users': 5, 'total_users': 9}, 
{'unregistered_users': 0, 'group_name': 'e', 'registered_users': 7, 'total_users': 7}, 
{'unregistered_users': 0, 'group_name': 'f', 'registered_users': 7, 'total_users': 7}]) is not JSON serializable
```

From what I can tell, this is valid JSON, and there's no reason why it shouldn't be serializable. I have pored through other SO questions regarding lack of JSON serializability and can't find any hints as to why this isn't working. My stack trace:

```
  File "/Users/AJ/code/my_app/events/views/event_views.py", line 50, in get
    return JsonResponse(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 530, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 121, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Using OS X, Python 3.5, Django 1.11, and a Postgres DB with UTF-8 encoding FWIW. Don't really know where to continue troubleshooting.

Code that throws the error:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponseForbidden
...
@method_decorator([need_jwt_verification, csrf_exempt], name="dispatch")
class EventController(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        event = self.eventService.get_event_details(id)
        ...
        return JsonResponse(event)
```

Comment: Please show us the code that produces the traceback, and tell us what you wanted to happen. Did you expect a JSON array with the values? then convert the dict view with a `list()` call first.

Comment: Updated my post to include that code. Yes, I expected a JSON array. It seems that I should not have to convert the dictionary to a list, since this same code works for others, and that this is a matter of configuration, rather than code specifics.

Comment: Your code only shows you called `self.eventService.get_event_details()`, we can't see that code.

Comment: Others are probably using Python 2, where `dict.values()` produces a list object. Python 3 `dict.values()` produces a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Comment: Yep, that was it. Wrapping the nested `dict_values` type property in `list(...)` fixed the problem. Thanks.